# How can I do select some columns of a relation in the resources model?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a model resource and I am calling **$this->tags** inside of it

This resource returns as the following:

```
"data": {
  "some_keys"  : ...,
  "some_keys2" : ...,
  "tags":[
           {
             "id": 1,
             "name": "c++",
             "parent_id": null,
             "type": null,
             "created_at": "2020-09-27 20:37:57",
             "updated_at": "2020-09-27 20:37:57",
             "pivot": {
                "task_id": 43,
                "skill_id": 1
             }
           }
        ]
```

I want to do as follows:

```
"data": {
  "some_keys"  : ...,
  "some_keys2" : ...,
  "tags": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "name": "c++"
            }
          ]
```

My resources Model:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    $data = parent::toArray($request);
    $data["tags"] = $this->tags;
    return $data;
}
```

My Task Model:

```
public function tags(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Skill::class, 'task_skills', 'task_id', 'skill_id');
}
```

How can I reduce some columns of tags in the resources model?

I solved it this way:

```
$data["tags"] = $this->tags->makeHidden(['pivot','created_at','updated_at','type','parent_id']);
```

Comment: If my answer does not solve your issue, please let me know more about your problem, so that I will be able to help you.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu I have tried 'only' and 'get', bot of them didnt solved my problem. When I used 'only', it returns empty array. And for get, it return null. Also I didnt want to use 'pluck'

Comment: So you want only tags and inside tags also you want only id and name?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu Not only tags, I just filter only tags that return id and name. This is the part I need to fix thats $this->tags

Comment: Okay, I will update my answer, can you edit your question and add how you are retrieving your data as traversing through collection will be inefficient.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a collection filter, but still not sure why you need to filter a collection, better to retrieve specific data using query itself.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu I have updated, maybe you can understand better. I don't want pivot and other keys as "parent_id", "created_at" etc.

Comment: I have updated my answer, but it seems collection methods can also do it, what output you were getting using those.

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few collection methods, which you are trying to achieve
based on that you can use.

**pluck**

```
$collection = collect([
    [
        'speakers' => [
            'first_day' => ['Rosa', 'Judith'],
            'second_day' => ['Angela', 'Kathleen'],
        ],
    ],
]);

$plucked = $collection->pluck('speakers.first_day');

$plucked->all();

// ['Rosa', 'Judith']
```

**only**

```
$collection = collect(['product_id' => 1, 'name' => 'Desk', 'price' => 100, 'discount' => false]);

$filtered = $collection->only(['product_id', 'name']);

$filtered->all();

// ['product_id' => 1, 'name' => 'Desk']
```

**get**

```
$collection = collect(['name' => 'taylor', 'framework' => 'laravel']);

$value = $collection->get('name');

// Taylor
```

If you always want to keeps some attributes [hidden](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json) you can use

`protected $hidden = ['parent_id', 'created_at'];` in your model

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::all()

Comment: @Furkanozturk can you paste a copy of your collection in your question or gist and share with me?

Comment: I solved by using makeHidden for other columns. Thanks for your efforts

Comment: @Furkanozturk okay.